# Do I have to secure an IKEA TV stand to the wall?

Tags: drill, self-assembly-furniture

I'm a young adult preparing to move out into an apartment the first time, and I'm trying to fill out some gaps in terms of furniture before I get going.

I found this IKEA tv stand that's perfectly small and cheap, but there's this business about anchoring it to the wall? I've never seen furniture anchored like that in my life!

Do you think it's really necessary to drill holes and all that fuss over such a small stand? (I'm looking at the MOSJO if that helps).

Edit: People keep mentioning kids. I'm moving out for the first time! I don't have a kid or pets! It's just me and a little apartment.

Comment: Pictures are always a big help in answering questions.

Comment: Don't buy furniture if you don't have a place to put it yet. And don't move assembled IKEA furniture. - So it's going to sit in the box until you move, and then you'll find out it doesn't fit in the nook where you want it anyway. *build to suit*. Not, *buy in preparation*; plenty of time for that later. - Try not to get too excited; 3 months from now you'll wish it was a bag of rice.

Comment: Depends very much on the specific stand.  Some would represent very little hazards, while others would be a much greater hazard.

Comment: For what it’s worth, anchoring it to the wall should be a fairly trivial procedure (one that this site no doubt can advise you on), and at least in my experience (many, many different apartments up and down the East Coast of the US over the past several years), landlords have no problem with tenants putting holes that size in walls (and if yours actually does, it’s also trivial to fix the hole after). So as you do the cost–benefit analysis, keep in mind that “anchoring it to the wall” should be evaluated a pretty minor cost.

Comment: I'm looking through the assembly instructions for the MOSJÖ (https://www.ikea.com/nl/nl/assembly_instructions/mosjo-tv-meubel__AA-338391-3_pub.pdf), and I'm not seeing anything about anchoring it to the wall. And given the low height and adjustable feet, I don't think it's necessary to anchor it.

Comment: Do you live in an earthquake zone?  I didn't either, until one happened.  Securing things makes sense.

Comment: I bought a cheap wire shelving unit from a large online retailer and it came with a wall anchor and anchor instructions. I generally plan to anchor all furniture if it is taller than it is wide or deep and I would be sad if it fell over.

Comment: Anchoring to the wall is generally very simple so I consider there to be no reason NOT to do it.

Comment: Regarding recent edit: Are you sure there will be no friend of yours visiting you with their kid(s) or pet(s)? And are you sure you and your guests will be sober all the time?

Comment: @UuDdLrLrSs - If you're living in a rented apartment anchoring to the wall may violate the terms of the lease.

Comment: @HotLicks It certainly *may*, but in my experience, it *doesn’t*. You’ll have to check with your lease/landlord, but every place I have been (and as I mentioned before, I’ve been moving around a lot), it’s been no problem. In fact, most places have **strongly** preferred hanging things on the wall with a nail or screw over attaching them to the wall with adhesive, e.g. Command Strips (not that you’d use adhesive for this).

Comment: Not a duplicate, but on the same topic - and one of my highest voted and favorite (because it is about safety and actually means something!) answers: https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/145348/should-i-tilt-my-diy-self-standing-bookshelf-backwards-to-prevent-it-falling-dow/145354#145354

Answer (score 32):

**No, nothing to do.**

If you download [the assembly instructions for MOSJÖ](https://www.ikea.com/us/en/assembly_instructions/mosjo-tv-unit__AA-338391-3_pub.pdf) you won’t see anything about a bracket for attaching the item to the wall, and there isn’t one included in the package.

Comment: While all the other answers are sound advice, this answer actually answers OP's question about his specific piece of furniture he wants to buy. The MOSJO is so low to the ground and quite wide so its almost as wide as it is tall that for it to topple over would require physical lifting of the unit. Would you mount a coffee table to the wall ?            As Robin mentioned it doesnt have wall mounts built it nor does it call for them to be added in the insutructions.

Comment: I would also add that any improvement of the MOSJÖ like attaching doors etc. needs to rethink the stability and probably add the wall mounts.

Comment: Wall anchors aren't included with IKEA furniture because it depends on the type of wall.

Comment: Sorry, I meant the typical bracket you get. I’ll edit my answer.

Comment: MOSJÖ is 15" tall. It's hard to imagine it falling in any direction.

Comment: The one caveat to this - If you've put a large TV on the stand, even though the stand itself is low, a knock what would only wobble the stand could be enough to knock over the TV breaking a device that's far more expensive than the stand.

Comment: @FreeMan While true that could literally happen to any unit imaginable regardless of whether it is mounted to the wall. The only way to avoid that would be to wall mount the TV, which makes the unit useless.

Answer (score 25):

"Why do I have to attach IKEA furniture to the wall specifically?  No other furniture seller requires this."

This is because of IKEA's iconography in the minds of the public.

If you buy a locally made TV stand from George Utrecht Family Furniture down on Mill Road, and a child climbs on it and it falls over, *you'd never dream of suing old George*.  You probably don't even know whose furniture that is.

The idea that furniture toppling was a dangerous threat *wasn't really coming together*, because it was 1000 worldwide accidents from furniture built by a thousand sellers, suits were rare, and no defendant ever had the marketing "punch" to get the message out.

Needless to say, with IKEA,  lawyers and bereaved *saw an opportunity to do some good*.  The bereaved were happy to trade away some settlement $, and IKEA was happy to participate.  And IKEA got the word out.

Unfortunately, people misconstrued this message to think **"only IKEA furniture needs to be anchored to the wall**.  No no!  What Ikea says about anchoring furniture applies to all furniture.

Comment: [Ikea Will Pay $46 Million to Parents of Toddler Crushed to Death by a Dresser](https://www.nytimes.com/2020/01/06/us/ikea-dresser-lawsuit-settlement.html) (nytimes). "The Swedish furniture retailer Ikea agreed to pay a $46 million settlement in a wrongful-death lawsuit brought by the parents of a California toddler who was crushed to death by a popular dresser model that had been recalled after at least five other children were killed." That's why.

Comment: I wholeheartedly disagree with this assessment.   No downvote but this simply isn't true.   The idea of fastening everything to a wall is ridiculous.   Each piece is its own assessment.   It is based on how the piece is made, center of gravity, extraneous forces (doors opening, drawers opening), who is in the house and has access to the furniture, the slope of the floor around the furniture and so on.   I have a TV stand that is pure metal with shelves made of tempered glass - at 70lbs+.   No way in world I need to anchor it... because it isn't cheap IKEA crap.   My IKEA crap is anchored.

Comment: @DMoore: You've apparently never lived in California.

Comment: @RobertHarvey - that would be part of the extraneous factors.  Also in my example my TV stand is 16 inches off the ground.  An NFL player can come at it will full force and hit it (not lift it up) and it wouldn't fall over and would probably barely move.   If I lived in California. I would definitely not be buying IKEA furniture  that stood greater than two feet high with kids in the house.

Answer (score 19):

**Perhaps not, but recognize the risks.**

A few years ago, there were several tragic accidents where young children were crushed by Ikea furniture. Since then, Ikea has issued recalls and safety warnings, instructing people to attach their furniture to the wall to avoid such incidents.

The piece you mention is only 30lbs (14 kg) and 15" (40 cm) tall, so it's unlikely to tip over, and unlikely to cause severe harm if it did, so it's a pretty low-risk piece of furniture even if you don't attach it to the wall. But do recognize that it can be a safety hazard, especially if you have rambunctious young children or pets.

As an adult with no kids who normally operates their furniture within the design parameters, however, I have never felt unsafe near an unsecured piece of Ikea furniture. The Ikea police won't track you down if you don't use the wall bracket, but you'll bear the full responsibility if there is an accident.

https://www.thesun.co.uk/living/2021262/why-does-ikea-furniture-fixed-wall/

Comment: For a lot of my furniture (bookcases, drawers, wardrobes) I place wedges under the front legs, to cause it to tip *back* against the wall slightly. This probably helps it toppling (and may need to be done anyone depending on how flat your floor is)

Comment: The simple way that toppling can occur is when drawers are pulled out and provide leverage against the center of mass, either by heavy contents or children's weight on them.

Comment: @DaveM yep, and customers tend to be outraged, if a drawer breaks off, stressed just barely (read: significantly) over its design load. (Which could have been a safety measure, though...) - So, probably, drawers are sturdier than they should (safely) be.

Comment: @I'mwithMonica but a single drawer needs to survive being pulled all the way out; and yet a single drawer probably won't topple the thing over.

Comment: Yes, but a child climbing the thing will pull out *all* the drawers, and then stand on them.

Answer (score 13):

I have put a lot of these IKEA TV stands together for people  and always suggest that they let me secure them to a wall. The old style TVs were so heavy that the stands were absolutely going no where but the flat screen TVs are light and high and can be positioned toward the front of the stand, making it easy to topple over. I know of adults that have toppled them over trying to get behind the stands to mess around with the cables. You might not have small children but you could have friends over that do. Play it safe and sink in a toggle bolt. Enjoy your new, first apartment and stay safe.

Comment: This is probably the right advice.   It is a safety issue... for the TV.   Why is no one worried about the TV?

Comment: Not just adults messing with the cables. Small kids being foolish. Cats being cats.

Comment: @DMoore the TV was my first thought, I just got here late...

Comment: @FreeMan - I have an 85" TV that is pretty high end... no way in the f'ing world would I put that on an IKEA TV stand.

Comment: @DMoore  You mean you don't think those little half turn bolts are good enough for your TV .. LOL?

Comment: @JACK - I put a full stop to IKEA crap after wife snuck in a dresser (which could easily kill a small child).   You shouldn't be able to nudge a piece of furniture and it wiggles.   That's my limit.

Comment: Reasonable-size TVs are $100 these days and not heavy enough to hurt anyone or be damaged if they fall. Just don't buy that 60" nonsense. Much less 85"

Answer (score 4):

If you have young children in your house I'd fasten it to the wall. Ikea started providing this as a standard after a child died after tipping over a piece of their furniture. If you don't have children it's not really necessary, just a thing Ikea's lawyers are telling them to include in all their furniture sets now.

https://www.usatoday.com/story/news/investigations/2020/01/06/ikea-settles-46-million-after-dresser-kills-child/2821182001/

Answer (score 4):

The IKEA piece in question would have come with a small metal bracket with screws. One arm of the bracket attaches to your furniture and the other arm has a largish hole in it which you have to figure out how to attach to your wall, the details of which depend very much on what your wall happens to be made of and how far away from it the piece is. People who *don't* live in earthquake zones will likely put these brackets in their junk drawers and forget about them.

As others have said, the risk of harm of the thing tipping over scales with (a) whether you live in an earthquake zone (b) whether you have toddlers in the home and (c) the weight of the thing that's resting on it. If the answers are No, No and Light, then you might well just not fret about it. If (a) is true then any local hardware store will advise you on how to secure furniture and if (b) is true then any of the dozen books your family has given you will have chapters on making your house child-safe (which involves strapping the tv to the stand, in addition to hooking the stand to the wall). If (c) is "heavy" then you've been suckered into taking your uncle's 36" trinitron that he doesn't know how to get rid of, and you should leave it at the curb and find a sale on a flat-panel.

As furniture goes, the Mosjo looks pretty ... can I say, "squat"? Not something that's going to flop over when a truck rumbles by. If it was a full-height Billy looming next to your futon, I'd say, yeah, tie that big boy to a stud. I had a room lined with Stens when I lived in San Francisco and you're damn right I hooked them to the walls ([lag thread screw hooks](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00OKG4UB0) into the studs, with short lengths of light chain around every second upright). In the absence of kids, I wouldn't worry about a low TV stand.

Answer (score 2):

As [Robin Whittleton](https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/191422/57016) correctly pointed out, MOSJÖ does not need to be anchored to walls, there's no such instruction in the manual and there are no anchoring parts provided.

Considering we're on Home Improvement site, you can add doors, shelves etc. to it on your own. From now on true common sense must work.

There are two modes of failure of the furniture one must take care of. It can either collapse unter the load or it can flip over. Anchoring addresses the second option.

Old furniture used to address the flipping by using heavy frame structure, light doors and few drawers close to floor. Those wont flip because the centre of mass is always in the furniture.

Younger pieces were proteced by screwing together building one big solid body that is heavy enough to be flipped easily.

New pieces are "design" and optimized for price. The result is lighter body structure and heavier doors, taller drawers etc. Glass, which is much heavier than wood, is used more and more. Such pieces must be anchored because even opening door or drawer can move the centre of mass too forward to flip it over.

Another point of view is stability of the whole setup. Older equpment is either smaller or heavier than today's equipment. TV sets were more like boxes (with all three dimensions simillar), new LCD/OLED/plasma screens are more like sheets (one dimension negligible to the other two). Speakers were rather heavy wooden boxes, now they are "design" tall tubes, shells etc.

Now imagine something hitting the MOSJÖ with 20" TV screen on it. It is light, so is the screen so the supports will skid slightly which will put the screen out of ballance, which is, unlike the MOSJÖ, thin and tall...

So, the answer is: "No, you don't need to secure IKEA TV stand to the wall" but if you do secure it properly, the security gain overcome the drawbacks with high margin.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably anchor most furniture to walls. Almost all furniture has a non neglible toppling hazard, and toppling is mesyy - you do not want your furniture and its contents damaged.

And this can happen easily, especially if your furniture has drawers or e.g. is top heavy.

You will need only very few equipment to secure your furniture and you probably need equipment anyway. E.g. a good cordless drill, screwdrivers, screws, etc. are mandatory for any househould. Otherwise you have to go borrow everything when you want to anything.